# Cant create service based database in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn C# and then I hit this roadblock. My Visual Studio 2010 wont let me create a service based database (the .mdf file). (Add>New Item>Service-Based Database)

Everytime I try to add new .mdf it would bring up an error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to the SQL server. The server was not found
>   or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I can create a Local Database (Add>New Item>Local Database) without any problem, but I cant create .mdf

I am running on Windows 7 64bit OS and Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate).

Comment: I am not really sure. How do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

A service-based database needs to connect to a SQL Server instance. It's not built into Visual Studio, it's a separate application which needs to be running somewhere for you to connect to. That error message is basically telling you it can't find the SQL Server instance you're trying to connect to.

Local Database works correctly because it keeps everything local to your application and doesn't require an external database server to function.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic requirements for using these two kinds of databases:**

- *Local Database (`.sdf`):* requires SQL Server Compact. That is, you need only an additional DLL, but no special system service. (If you know SQLite: SQL Server Compact is conceptually the same thing, only more powerful and feature-complete.)
- *Service-Based Database (`.mdf` & `.ldf` log/journal file):* requires a running instance of SQL Server or SQL Server Express, both of which are standalone products ([as Tim Copenhaver points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13128688/240733)). For development purposes, you'd typically install one of these products on your development machine.

**Likely cause of your problem:** Guessing from the error message that you posted, you do not have SQL Server, nor SQL Server Express, installed. However, an instance of one of these products is required so that you can "attach" your database to it. This is required in order before you can actually access the `.mdf` database.

**To see whether you have SQL Server installed,** you could e.g. open Control Panel → Administrative Tools → Services, and look out for a system service named "SQL Server (`.\SQLEXPRESS`)", or "SQL Server (`YOURCOMPUTERNAME\MSSQLSERVER`)", or similar. The name in the brackets is the name of the database instance running on your machine. `SQLEXPRESS` is the default instance name for SQL Server Express, while `MSSQLSERVER` is the default instance name for the full version of SQL Server.

**If you do not have SQL Server installed,** you can download e.g. [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) or [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438) for free from Microsoft.

Comment: how do i check if I have an SQL Server / SQL Server express installed? I thought they were bundled with Visual Studio when you install it since VS2010 installed LOTS of things and I opted to just install them all.

Comment: I think I found a match, or not? 

http://s8.postimage.org/l7685ipv9/Untitled.jpg

print screened the image

Comment: @brian3415: You appear to have SQL Server Express installed, but the main service is not running, and some of the other related services are disabled. Try **1.** enabling the two disabled services *SQL Server Agent (…)* and *SQL Server Browser*, then **2.** start the *SQL Server* service; and finally **3.** re-try creating & attaching a service-based DB from Visual Studio. (In case you're being asked for connection details: You'll want to attach it to the local instance called `.\SQLEXPRESS` during development.)

Comment: I put every SQL in automatic then right clicked>start the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service and it showed this message.

http://s10.postimage.org/mhwklcs21/Untitled2.png

visual studio still wont let me add new .mdf files

Comment: Now that's an altogether different question than the one you initially asked, and I cannot help you with that. For a start, do what the error message suggests and check the system event log (also in *Control Panel* > *Administrative Tools*) for cues about potential error causes. Please note that since this is a different question ("How do I troubleshoot this particular SQL Server service start-up problem?"), check whether that question has already been asked & answered; or, if you need further help, I suggest that you ask it as a separate question on the appropriate site!

Comment: do you think that this error is what prevents me from creating .mdf? maybe I should just install a 2012 version?

Comment: First question: It seems likely. Second question: I don't know. (But I suggest you try to find the cause of that error; trying to solve this problem will likely improve your problem solving skills more than just randomly installing another product, IMHO.)

Comment: ok thanks for your replies :) I really appreciated them! I will now ask a new question about this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Go to Command Prompt from Start->Run(type cmd -> press enter)
2. Check  SqlLocalDB by

   Sqllocaldb.exe i

   You will see version number like (v11.0) otherwise complete the 
   installation.
3. Create the sqldb by

   sqllocaldb c dbname

   You will see like "LocalDB instance "dbname" created with version 11.0."
4. Then Start the Db

   sqllocaldb s dbname

   You will see like "LocalDB instance "dbname" started"
5. See the created Db info

   sqllocaldb.exe i dbname

Now try to create service-based database in c#.

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily attach a database file (.mdf) from the Data Connections node

1. In Server Explorer, open the short cut menu for Data Connections and choose Add Connection.
   The Add Connection dialogue box appears.
2. Choose the Change button.
   The Change Data Source dialogue box appears.
3. Select Microsoft SQL Server Database File and choose the OK button.
   The Add Connection dialogue box reappears, with Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) shown in the Data source text box.
4. Choose the Browse button and browse to an existing .mdf file.
   If you type a file name that does not exist, a blank .mdf file will be created.
5. Select either Use Windows Authentication or Use SQL Server Authentication.
   For more information on SQL Server database access authentication, see Create New SQL Server Database Dialogue Box.
6. Choose the OK button.
   The database appears in Server Explorer.